# How to add primes in a numbering environment

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I am writing my thesis, and I need to add primes to certain proposition numbers. For instance, I have a proposition:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Proposition
\end{enumerate}
```

Which prints out something like this:

1. Proposition

And that is perfectly fine. However, I later edit that proposition in the paper, so I need something to give me this:

1'. Proposition + edit

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` package and its `label={...}` option, adding the `\prime`. Or define a separate list for this, like `primenumerate`:

It's even possible to resume the list and start again this list, this time as a `primenumerate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\newlist{primenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[primenumerate,1]{label={\arabic*$'$}}


\begin{document}





\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*$'$}]
\item Proposition
\end{enumerate}

Or

\begin{primenumerate}
\item Proposition
\end{primenumerate}


Or

\begin{enumerate}[series=first]
\item Proposition
\item Other proposition
\end{enumerate}

And now let us resume this and restart!

\begin{primenumerate}[resume=first,start=2]
\item Proposition
\end{primenumerate}




\end{document}
```

[image]